# C - Timing my program in seconds with microsecond precision on

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to find out the user time (on a Linux machine) of C program I've written. Currently I'm calling gettimeofday() once at the beginning of my code and once at the end. I'm using the timeval struct and difftime(stop.tv_sec,start.tv_sec) to get the number of seconds elapsed. This returns whole seconds, like "1.000000". However, my project requires that my program be timed in seconds with microsecond precision, for example "1.234567". How can I find this value? I know gettimeofday() also records microseconds in .tv_usec, but I'm not sure how to use this value and format it correctly.

Comment: Simply do not ignore the `tv_usec`-struct-members, but include them in your calculation?

Comment: This is OS-specific if you really get that resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `timersub` function. It takes three arguments: the first is the initial time, the second the final one, and the third is the result (the diference). All of the three arguments are pointers to `timeval` struct.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the initial time into storage then subtract that from the final time when you are done.

```
storedValue = timer.tv_sec + 0.000001 * timer.tv_usec
timer.tv_sec + 0.000001 * timer.tv_usec - storedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want microseconds:

```
long long usec;

usec = tv.tv_sec;
usec *= 1000000;
usec += tv.tv_usec;
```

If you want fractional seconds [floating point]:

```
double asec;

asec = tv.tv_usec;
asec /= 1e6;
asec += tv.tv_sec;
```

---

Here are some complete functions:

```
// tvsec -- get current time in absolute microseconds
long long
tvsec(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    long long usec;

    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);

    usec = tv.tv_sec;
    usec *= 1000000;
    usec += tv.tv_usec;

    return usec;
}

// tvsecf -- get current time in fractional seconds
double
tvsecf(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    double asec;

    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);

    asec = tv.tv_usec;
    asec /= 1e6;
    asec += tv.tv_sec;

    return asec;
}
```

---

Note: If you want even higher accuracy (e.g. nanoseconds), you can use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)` and apply similar conversions